# Move controls on View from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to make a monopoly game using the WPF, Prism and MVVM.
On my View I have a grid divided into several rows and columns. Each cell is a separate game card, for example, a city.

I also have a content controls which displays my players as chips.

The task is to move my players, relative to the cells in the grid.
And I need to do this from my ViewModel.(I want my ViewModel tells somehow to my View where to locate player). Just help me with approach to this problem.

My View:

```
            <!--bottom row-->
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="10" Content="{Binding Cards[0]}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardTemplateSelector}"/>
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="9" Content="{Binding Cards[1]}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardTemplateSelector}"/>
            ...

            <!--left column-->
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Cards[11]}"  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardTemplateSelector}"/>
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Cards[12]}"  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardTemplateSelector}"/>
            ...

            <!--top row-->
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Cards[20]}"  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CardTemplateSelector}"/>
            ...

            <!--right column-->
            ...

            <!--player chips-->
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="10" Content="{Binding Players[0]}"  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PlayerTemplate1}"/>
            ...
```

What I expect:
1)Model makes a dice roll(actually i have done this)
2)ViewModel gets this result and transform it to position on grid(have some ideas)
3)View must somehow get this position and move my player.

Comment: You can try placing the player's content controls in each cell then use a visibility converter to only display them at their current position.

Comment: [My answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563181/1177147) should provide you with enough to get started.

Comment: Thank you @MarkFeldman! Can you help another one?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you MarkFeldman!Your approach helped me. But i have another problem now))

For this moment my players can move all around the game board. It's great! But, I want to simulate the passage of cards one by one, and not immediately to the final card. First I tried to make one step, thread.sleep(100) and then again step until in the right place. But this led to a complete freeze of the program until the chip was in the final card.

I would be grateful for one more hint.

Comment: Consider posting a new question for a new problem, instead of posting it as an answer to your original question.

Answer (score -1):

```
    internal void MakeStep()
    {
        this.CardIndex++;
    }

    internal void MakeStep(int count)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.StepByStep(count));

    }

    private void StepByStep(int count)
    {
        for (int i = count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.MakeStep();
                Debug.Print(this.CardIndex.ToString());
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Here is my solution for simulating the passage of cards one by one. The problem was in threading!